# Multiplication of 2 matrix in verilog

Tags: verilog

I've written a code for matrx multiplication in Verilog.

```
module multiply3x3(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6,i7,i8,i9,j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,j6,j7,j8,j9,prod);

output reg [31:0]prod;

wire [7:0]resultant[3:0][3:0]; 
wire [7:0]a[3:0][3:0];
wire [7:0]b[3:0][3:0]; 

genvar i,j,k;

generate

for (i = 0; i <= 2; i=i+1) begin:i_
      for (j = 0; j <= 2; j=j+1) begin:j_
         assign resultant[i][j] = 8'd0;
         for (k = 0; k <= 2; k=k+1) begin:k_
            assign resultant[i][j] = resultant[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
         end
      end
   end

endgenerate   

endmodule
initial begin
#100 prod = {resultant[0][0],resultant[0][1],resultant[0][2],resultant[1][0],resultant[1][1],resultant[1][2],resultant[2][0],resultant[2][1],resultant[2][2]};
end
```

This is where the multiplication happens, but i cannot get the output for this.

What am I doing wrong?
consider a,b declared properly.

Comment: this cannot work in `verilog` due to the multi-dimensional arrays. Try `system verilog`. Also you have  zero-delay loops with `resultant[i][j]`

Comment: @toolic here's the test fixture: https://pastebin.com/cwjnimMf

Comment: @toolic The complete verilog code: https://pastebin.com/txrcwUBd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accumulation (a = a + p) doesn't work with wires. The type `wire` is supposed to model a physical wire.

You'll have to declare the variable `resultant` as a `reg`. The `reg` type, in Verilog, can in some cases be treated like a variable in other programming languages. 
Also, you can't use the `assign` statement on a wire or reg multiple times (like you've done in line 78 and 80 of https://pastebin.com/txrcwUBd). You should use `always` (and not `generate`) blocks to perform such things.

Corrected Verilog:

```
reg [7:0] resultant[3:0][3:0];
int i, j, k;

always @(*)
   for(i=0; i<3; i=i+1)
      for(j=0; j<3; j=j+1) begin
         resultant[i][j] = 8'd0;
         for(k=0; k<3; k=k+1)
            resultant[i][j] = resultant[i][j] + (a[i][k]*b[k][j]);
      end
```